# Sudden loss of bluetooth on Surface Pro 6

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microsoft-surface

I was happily working away when my my microsoft mouse lost connection.
As I started to dig, it appears the bluetooth has somehow failed and I cannot get it to work again.

More information -

- I was purely searching the web at the time
- I had not installed any any new software or drivers of any sort
- Last windows update of any sort was 14 days ago
- There are no bluetooth errors in the event logs
- The enable button for bluetooth is missing in the settings screen
- Bluetooth only appeared in device manager when "show hidden devices" is enabled
- Under properties of the hidden bluetooth device, it says the "hardware is not connected to the system"
- Bluetooth is on in the UEFI (I've even turned it off, restarted, on, restart)
- I uninstalled the bluetooth adapter in device manager, and did a restart
- Now nothing bluetooth related appears in device manager

Tried a bunch of suggestions from various websites, but no luck.
Ideas ?

Comment: You should have just restarted without uninstalling the driver to begin with. You don't mention if you reinstalled drivers, or did a repair on Windows, or ran system restore.

Comment: Did do a plain restart before uninstalling drivers, just didn't mention. Cant reinstall drivers the device does not even appear in device manager any more. It is as though I physically removed the device. Have not tried a restore yet. Wanted to explore simpler options first